# Gather information from a web page to the desktop?

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel

Does anyone know a way to gather a bunch of information from a web page (like Excel does) to display it right into a widget or anything easy readable on the desktop?

**Example** : http://www.fear.fm/radio/program/the-z/77/session/662

The goal is to take the tracklist and display it elsewhere, preferably on the desktop.

Comment: Like a RSS reader or XML?

Comment: This sort of depends on the website and the information you want, and what format it's in.  Can you be more specific, especially if it's an EXISTING website rather than you're-thinking-about-making-one?

Comment: @ngen Kinda, but the pages i'm talking about does not provide any feed like those...

Comment: Can you provide an example website?

Comment: @Shinrai The page exists, but the other issue is that the page I want the infos from is always different. But that's another story.

Comment: @J4cK - Ouch.  The answer is 'it'll probably be difficult unless you're lucky', but really nobody can answer without some concrete examples because there's just too many possibilities.

Comment: I put the example in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forgot this great Adobe Air "widget" which provides a simple way to do what I want without bothering with text and stuff. It's called **Snippage**. 
Thanks for the help anyway !

http://snippage.gabocorp.com/

Comment: Oh wow, this is really neat.  So basically it's just pulling the site and only rendering the part you want?  I like it.